# How to build a string that then gets passed to printf?

Tags: python

There is code like this:

```
print(f'Pair: {symbol} Bid Price: {bid:.2f} Bid Size: {bid_size:.6f} Bid Feed: {bid_feed} Ask Price: {ask:.2f} Ask Size: {ask_size:.6f} Ask Feed: {ask_feed}')
```

How do I similarly build the string that is passed to `printf`? This doesn't work:

```
msg = f'Pair: {symbol} Bid Price: {bid:.2f} Bid Size: {bid_size:.6f} Bid Feed: {bid_feed} Ask Price: {ask:.2f} Ask Size: {ask_size:.6f} Ask Feed: {ask_feed}'

print(msg)
```

Comment: `print(msg)`. `printf` is not a thing in python

Comment: I don't undestrand the question. What kind  of function is `printf`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. You might have mistype `print` to `printf` like the comment of @rdas suggests.

you can either do:

```
print('sum = %d' % x)
print(f'sum = {x}')
print('sum = {price}'.format(price = x))
print('sum = {0}'.format(x))
print('sum = ' + str(x))
```